# Spring boot 2.1.1 + Oauth2 add Roles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Spring Boot application which has OAuth2 at every Controller, but I also want to add Role based security to the methods within the controller based on the user who is accessing the mehtod, but I cant get it to work. Any suggestions ?

My security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private static final RequestMatcher PUBLIC_URLS = new OrRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/public/**"));
private static final RequestMatcher PRIVATE_URLS = new NegatedRequestMatcher(PUBLIC_URLS);

private TokenAuthenticationProvider tokenProvider;

public SecurityConfiguration(TokenAuthenticationProvider tokenAuthenticationProvider) {
    this.tokenProvider = tokenAuthenticationProvider;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth.authenticationProvider(tokenProvider);
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().requestMatchers(PUBLIC_URLS);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
    .exceptionHandling().defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(forbiddenEntryPoint(), PRIVATE_URLS).and()
    .authenticationProvider(tokenProvider).addFilterBefore(restAuthenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests().requestMatchers(PRIVATE_URLS).authenticated().
    .csrf().disable()
    .formLogin().disable()
    .httpBasic().disable()
    .logout().disable();
}

@Bean
public TokenAuthenticationFiller restAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    TokenAuthenticationFiller filler = new TokenAuthenticationFiller(PRIVATE_URLS);
    filler.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    filler.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler());
    return filler;
}

@Bean
public SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
    SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    successHandler.setRedirectStrategy(new NoRedirectStrategy());
    return successHandler;
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean disableAutoRegistration(TokenAuthenticationFiller tokenAuthenticationFiller) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(tokenAuthenticationFiller);
    registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
    return registrationBean;
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationEntryPoint forbiddenEntryPoint() {
    return new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
}
```